# Swashbuckle fails in asp.net core with NotSupportedException exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swashbuckle

I followed this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) on how to add swashbuckle in my asp.net core 2.2 project.

As soon as I run the project I get following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>       NotSupportedException: HTTP method "GET" & path "{id}" overloaded by actions - dotnet1.Server.Controllers.UsersController.GetById
>   (dotnet1.Server),dotnet1.Server.Controllers.ValuesController.Get
>   (dotnet1.Server). Actions require unique method/path combination for
>   Swagger 2.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround

Don't understand what is the issue here.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that didn't require us to look at an external link (most people won't do that).

Comment: See the exception class for common cases where it should be used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception?view=netframework-4.7.2 As get is mention, I guess this is a webAPI. And apaprently your WebAPI call is not supported. it is often used if you have to have a function (you have to implement a .NET Interface), but can not get a meaningfull code for it.

Comment: you need to share your controller's code

Answer (score 2):

try putting get method:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
```

you must differentiate your methods and map correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar and resolved it by configuring the MVC routes to be more explicit.

I wanted to have `HTTPGET /users/{id}` for a single user and `HTTPGET /users?role={role}`.

So, based on what I read in a comment on this Github issue linked below, I did the following when configuring my MVC routes.

```c#
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "single",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{id}");
});
```

[Related Github Issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/142#issuecomment-220560708)

Answer (score 0):

This is common while using Swagger.  The real error here is this

> Actions require unique method/path combination for Swagger 2.0. Use
>   ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround

The swagger seems to work.  This is a general error we get when our controllers are named differently.

1) Check for duplicate names in action methods.  Change the name of the error causing GET action method to something else and try?

I have faced this error in my aspnet core app and fixed it like that.

Your issue could be related to [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/142)

> Swashbuckle will raise an exception if it encounters multiple actions with the same path (sans query string) and HTTP method

The link has a solution for your problem.